# Problemas com xml em diferentes tamanhos de telas

Tags: android, android-xml

Boa tarde, não estou conseguindo entender como faz a compatibilidade de varios tamanhos de tela em minha aplicação, olhei na internet e no youtube e lá fala para criar uma pasta dentro de res com o nome layout-small **que no caso seria para tamanhos de telas pequenas** mas fica aparecendo um erro em meu xml e não consigo executrar o aplicativo... Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pasta que você tem que criar é `res\layout-small` e não `res\layout\layout-small`

Segue tutorial oficial da Google de como projetar para vários tamanhos de tela: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html